# How to pass connection success or failure to the caller in the Twisted framework?

Tags: python, twisted, twisted.internet

After working through some of the basic [tutorials](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/clients.html), I want my TCP/UDP client to exit with a code indicating whether it connected or not.  The right way to return an exit code in Twisted is:

```
point = TCP4ClientEndpoint(reactor, "localhost", 1234)
d = connectProtocol(point, ClientProtocol())
reactor.run()
sys.exit(0)
```

Then, when the process terminates, it will exit with code 0 to indicate a normal termination.  If the client instead times out instead of successfully connecting, how should it pass a value back to that can then be passed to sys.exit instead of the constant 0?

Comment: Use a function and `return` the exit code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Determining whether the TCP connection succeeded or failed is accomplished by attending to the result of the Deferred:

```
d = connectProtocol(point, ClientProtocol())
d.addCallbacks(
    connected,
    did_not_connect,
)
```

With appropriate implementations of `connected` and `did_not_connect`, you should be able to pass a suitable value to a subsequent `sys.exit` call.

For example,

```
class Main(object):
    result = 1

    def connected(self, passthrough):
        self.result = 0
        return passthrough

    def did_not_connect(self, passthrough):
        self.result = 2
        return passthrough

    def exit(self):
        sys.exit(self.result)

main = Main()
d = connectProtocol(point, ClientProtocol())
d.addCallbacks(
    main.connected,
    main.did_not_connect,
)
reactor.run()
main.exit()
```

Comment: Because I need to support UDP too, I couldn't use callbacks (AFAICT, listenUDP doesn't return a Deferred instance), so I had to take a slightly different approach that's morally the same: add the twisted.protocols.policies.TimeoutMixin to the protocol classes, set an instance variable in timeoutConnection(), and read the instance variable in the sys.exit() call.  This unfortunately involves what I was hoping to avoid, using a global instance to pass state set in non-`__init__` methods, but it doesn't seem like there's another way to do it.

Comment: UDP clients don't meaningfully fail to connect.  listenUDP succeeds synchronously.  Regardless, the same approach as I outlined in this answer can be used to avoid global state elsewhere as well.